# What software for local VOIP Intercom (Linux Server, Smartphone app)

Tags: communication

I am looking for a wireless intercom solution where I can at least have 5 Clients (4 Camera Ops and one Video Director).

It needs to be able to do the following:

- Works completely Locally over wifi (no internet uplink present)
- smartphone clients for ios and android
- server should be linux (or no server at all)
- extremely low latency (video director needs to be able to give the camera ops cues in time)
- ideally either no audio filtering or filtering that works in concert situations